# How to interpolate missing values with groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I cannot get missing values to interpolate correctly when I use the groupby function.

Here is a quick example of what I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create data
state = pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'])
population = pd.Series([100, 150, np.nan, np.nan, 50, 125, np.nan, np.nan])
year = [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]
dict = {'state': state, 'population': population, 'year': year}  
df = pd.DataFrame(dict) 

# Interpolate population, grouped by states
df.groupby('state').apply(lambda x: x.interpolate(method='linear')) 

  state  population  year
0     A       100.0  2016
1     A       150.0  2017
2     A       150.0  2018
3     A       150.0  2019
4     B        50.0  2016
5     B       125.0  2017
6     B       125.0  2018
7     B       125.0  2019
```

As you notice, when grouping by `state`, it is simply repeating the last value.

Comment: From a data perspective, you are actually asking pandas to extrapolate after the last year, so with the limited data you have shown in the sample, it isn't necessarily wrong to infer that the next years population is the same as the previous (in absence of extra information)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And base on what you need , pass the method `spline`

```
df.groupby('state')['population'].apply(lambda x : x.interpolate(method = "spline", order = 1, limit_direction = "both"))
0    100.0
1    150.0
2    200.0
3    250.0
4     50.0
5    125.0
6    200.0
7    275.0
Name: population, dtype: float64
```